# Converting a math formula into MATLAB code

Tags: matlab

How I can convert this math formula to a vectorized MATLAB code?

```
a(i) = Sum (Log (b(i) / b(i-1)) - Sum (Log (b(i) / b(i-1)), 10) , 10 )
```

`b` is a vector and `i > 10`.

Also, `Sum (d(i),n) = d(i) + d(i-1) + ... + d(i-n+1)`, with `i > n`

Comment: yes but this formula is not a code matlab

Comment: I just want to transform the formula into matlab code. I will adjust after the index problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before coding the formula in MATLAB, there is a great deal of simplification you can perform. First, define a function `f(i)` as follows:

```
f(i) = Log(b(i)/b(i-1)) = Log(b(i)) - Log(b(i-1))
```

Then, applying the `Sum` function as you have defined it, you can see that many of the terms cancel one another out:

```
Sum(f(i),10) = f(i) + f(i-1) + ... + f(i-8) + f(i-9)
             = Log(b(i))   - Log(b(i-1)) +
               Log(b(i-1)) - Log(b(i-2)) +
               ... +
               Log(b(i-8)) - Log(b(i-9)) +
               Log(b(i-9)) - Log(b(i-10))

==> Sum(f(i),10) = Log(b(i)) - Log(b(i-10))
```

Now, here's where it gets a little tricky, because there are potentially two ways to interpret your nested `Sum` operations: one where the inner summation variable `i` *depends* on the outer summation variable `i`, and one where the inner summation variable `i` is *independent* of the outer summation variable `i`.

### When the inner `i` depends on the outer `i`...

then for every term of the outer summation, the inner summation is computed starting from the decremented value of `i` for that term. For example, the fifth term of the outer summation would look like this:

```
... + f(i-4) - Sum(f(i-4),10) + ...
```

The equation for `a(i)` will therefore simplify as follows:

```
a(i) = Sum(f(i) - Sum(f(i),10),10)
     = Sum(Log(b(i)) - Log(b(i-1)) - Log(b(i)) + Log(b(i-10)),10)
     = Sum(Log(b(i-10)) - Log(b(i-1)),10)
     = Log(b(i-10)) - Log(b(i-1)) +
       Log(b(i-11)) - Log(b(i-2)) +
       ... + 
       Log(b(i-18)) - Log(b(i-9)) +
       Log(b(i-19)) - Log(b(i-10))

              [b(i-11)*b(i-12)*...*b(i-18)*b(i-19)]
==> a(i) = Log[-----------------------------------]
              [  b(i-1)*b(i-2)*...*b(i-8)*b(i-9)  ]
```

And this final equation can be coded in MATLAB as follows:

```
a(i) = log(prod(b(i-(11:19)))/prod(b(i-(1:9))));
```

### When the inner `i` is independent of the outer `i`...

then the result of the inner summation will essentially appear to be a constant with respect to the outer summation. For example, the fifth term of the outer summation would look like this:

```
... + f(i-4) - Sum(f(i),10) + ...
```

The equation for `a(i)` will therefore simplify as follows:

```
a(i) = Sum(f(i) - Sum(f(i),10),10)
     = Sum(f(i),10) - 10*Sum(f(i),10)
     = -9*Sum(f(i),10)
     = 9*Log(b(i-10)) - 9*Log(b(i))

==> a(i) = 9*Log(b(i-10)/b(i))
```

And this final equation can be coded in MATLAB as follows:

```
a(i) = 9*log(b(i-10)/b(i));
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what concept you are expressing here (your formula doesn't have matched parentheses!) but if that's truly what you want, you could simplify as follows:

```
log(b(i:i+9)./b(i-1:i+8))
```

is  equivalent to

```
 diff(log(b(i-1:i+9)))
```

So

I would transform b into log returns first:

```
c = diff(log(b));
```

then

```
a(i+1) = sum( c(i:i+9) - sum(c(i:i+9)));
```

Perhaps with the formula simplified, you can see more clearly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`a(i) = sum( log(b(i-9:i:)./b(i-10:i-1)) - sum(log(b(i-9:i)./b(i-10:i-1))))`

Consider `Sum(f(i), n)`. It is equivalent to `sum(f(i-n+1:i))`. So `Sum(Log(f(i)), n)` is `sum(log(f(i-n+1:i)))` (take elementwise operation, and then sum the result).

**EDIT**

Mathematically, isn't

```
Sum(Log(b(i)/b(i-1)), n)
= \sum_{j=0..n-1}(Log(b(i-j)/b(i-j-1)))
= \sum_{j=0..n-1}(Log(b(i-j)) - Log(b(i-j-1)))
= Log(b(i)) - Log(b(i-n))
= Log(b(i)/b(i-n))
```

??

So then,

```
a(i) = Sum(Log(b(i)/b(i-1)) - Sum(Log(b(i)/b(i-1)), n)  , n)
= Sum(Log(b(i)/b(i-1)), n) - Sum(Sum(Log(b(i)/b(i-1)), n), n)
= Log(b(i)/b(i-n)) - Sum(Log(b(i)/b(i-n)), n)
```

??

The problem is with the definition of `Sum`. which really should specify the index.

And how does the inner `Sum`'s index interact with the outer sum's (both are `i`).

Comment: thank you lijie for your answer, but in formula Log (b (i) / b (i-1)) is a scalar, while in your response, it is a vector.

Comment: in fact, log (b (i) / b (i-1)) is a scalar and Sum (Log (b (i) / b (i-1)), 10) gives another scalar which is the sum of the last 10 values of log (b (i) / b (i-1)).

Comment: so, a(i) is the sum of the last 10 values of the result: log (b (i) / b (i-1)) - Sum (Log (b (i) / b (i-1))

Comment: oh i read the definition of sum wrongly (read the `-` as `+`). will adjust the answer.